# Values pointed by the pointer are overwritten

Tags: c++

Currently im trying to build a tree using connected nodes using Huffman's algorithm. But currently I have a problem where the values pointed by the parentNode is getting overwritten on every loop. How can i make 2 variables that are re-initialized every loop in order to add new values and not get overwritten.

```cpp
void buildHuff(Queue* priorityQueue, treeNode* rootNode) {
    while (priorityQueue->b != priorityQueue->f) { // Check if Queue doesn't have one element left.
        treeNode *parentNode = (treeNode*)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
        treeNode firstItem;
        treeNode secondItem;
        dequeue(priorityQueue, &firstItem);
        dequeue(priorityQueue, &secondItem);
        parentNode->data = '#';
        parentNode->frequency = (firstItem.frequency + secondItem.frequency);
        parentNode->left = &firstItem;
        parentNode->right = &secondItem;
        firstItem.parent = parentNode;
        secondItem.parent = parentNode;
        if (priorityQueue->items > 0) {
            enqueue(priorityQueue, *parentNode);
            free(parentNode);
        }
        else {
            rootNode = parentNode;
        }
        if (priorityQueue->items > 1) sortQueue(priorityQueue);
    }
}
```

The values of `parentNode->left` and `parentNode->right` are being overwritten on every new parentNode created every new loop.

Comment: Please, always post a [mcve] rather than a incomplete code snippet.

Comment: You are pointing `parentNode->left` and `parentNode->right` to local variables that go out of scope on each loop iteration. `dequeue()` and `enqueue()` should be operating on `treeNode*` pointers, not `treeNode` instances

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, the thing is how can i recreate this code in a better way in wich firstItem & secondItem are re-used but don't get overwritten on each `parentNode->left` and `parentNode->right`?

Comment: @Youssef they need to be pointers instead, and you need to change your queue accordingly to hold pointers

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you, problem was solved as you said. I just allocated new memory space for them on every loop and it worked perfectly, and i can deallocate them at the very end when I no longer need the data pointed by the `parentNode->left` and `parentNode->right`
that's what i did to fix it
`treeNode* firstItem = (treeNode*)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));`
`treeNode* secondItem = (treeNode*)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));`

Comment: Consider writing an answer and accepting it as the solution.